# Getting the text of dynamically generated TextViews inside a Linear Layout and storing it in a String array

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, textview

How to get the text of the textViews inside the linear layout ?
I am basically going to put the code under onSavedInstance with which I am going to display the textViews as such in the linearLayout in case of a change of screen orientation.

I have modified the below code

```
for (int i = 0; i < ll1.getChildCount(); i++) {


    }
```

as

```
for (int i = 0; i < ll1.getChildCount(); i++) {
        TextView children = (TextView) ll1.getChildAt(i);
        String b1 = (String) children.getText().toString();
    }
```

I have tried the above code, but could not find any success.

Comment: Do you get any errors? What about this code isn't working?

Comment: No, The emulator exits the application on Screen rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String[] bArray = new String[ll1.getChildCount()];

for (int i = 0; i < ll1.getChildCount(); i++) {
    TextView children = (TextView) ll1.getChildAt(i);
    String b = children.getText().toString();
    bArray[i] = b;
}
```

This might work if your linear layout contains only textviews. Else you will have to give all your textviews id such as txtView1, txtView2, etc and fetch it using id.

**Edit:**

To return all children into one single string, try this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(ll1.getChildCount());
for (int i = 0; i < ll1.getChildCount(); i++) {
    TextView children = (TextView) ll1.getChildAt(i);
    sb.append(children.getText().toString()+" ");
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is what i needed. Is there any other efficient way to retrieve the values of a _dynamically-generated-textView_ when the screen orientation changes?

Comment: @Madhan I am not aware of it. sorry :/

Comment: Can you get this code to get all children into one single string?

Comment: @ViolinNz yes, yu can. Check the edited answer. Sorry for late response. I was on leave :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this. In your **layout xml** file set the tag as txtview like the following

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tag="txtview"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tag="txtview"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tag="txtview"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:tag="txtview"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

and use the following code in your **activity**

```
    LinearLayout ll1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(your layout id);

    String[] bArray;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < ll1.getChildCount(); i++) {
        if (ll1.getChildAt(i).getTag().equals("txtview")) {
            TextView children = (TextView) ll1.getChildAt(i);
            stringBuilder.append(children.getText().toString() + "!##!");
        }
    }
    bArray = stringBuilder.toString().split("!##!");
```

Comment: I use **dynamically generated textViews**.

Comment: while creating the textview add code for setting the tag like: children.setTag("your tag like txtview"); where childeren is textview